# One Codeigniter website and application together

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a Codeigniter website and i want users and admins to be able to access the respective systems through the main website example showed below, I have the main controller set in routes.php and I have generated folders for admin and user under the controller folder and Views folder. The main website works well but when I click the links to go to login for admin or user I get a 404 error, am not sure if i have implemented the structure correctly or its the logic which is wrong. This is an example of how am calling the user login from the main site

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/user.php">
```

Routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Main website
[image: Main codeigniter website]

Project tree structure

```
Fun4lend
├─ .editorconfig
├─ .gitignore
├─ application
│  ├─ .htaccess
│  ├─ config
│  │  ├─ autoload.php
│  │  ├─ config.php
│  │  ├─ constants.php
│  │  ├─ database.php
│  │  ├─ doctypes.php
│  │  ├─ foreign_chars.php
│  │  ├─ hooks.php
│  │  ├─ index.html
│  │  ├─ memcached.php
│  │  ├─ migration.php
│  │  ├─ mimes.php
│  │  ├─ profiler.php
│  │  ├─ routes.php
│  │  ├─ smileys.php
│  │  └─ user_agents.php
│  ├─ controllers
│  │  ├─ admin
│  │  │  └─ Welcome.php
│  │  ├─ Auth.php
│  │  ├─ home.php
│  │  ├─ index.html
│  │  └─ user
│  │     └─ Auth.php
│  ├─ core
│  │  └─ index.html
│  ├─ helpers
│  │  └─ index.html
│  ├─ hooks
│  │  └─ index.html
│  ├─ index.html
│  ├─ language
│  │  ├─ english
│  │  │  └─ index.html
│  │  └─ index.html
│  ├─ libraries
│  │  └─ index.html
│  ├─ models
│  │  ├─ index.html
│  │  └─ register_model.php
│  ├─ third_party
│  │  └─ index.html
│  └─ views
│     ├─ about.php
│     ├─ about_us.php
│     ├─ admin
│     ├─ errors
│     │  ├─ cli
│     │  │  ├─ error_404.php
│     │  │  ├─ error_db.php
│     │  │  ├─ error_exception.php
│     │  │  ├─ error_general.php
│     │  │  ├─ error_php.php
│     │  │  └─ index.html
│     │  ├─ html
│     │  │  ├─ error_404.php
│     │  │  ├─ error_db.php
│     │  │  ├─ error_exception.php
│     │  │  ├─ error_general.php
│     │  │  ├─ error_php.php
│     │  │  └─ index.html
│     │  └─ index.html
│     ├─ homepage.php
│     ├─ home_loan.php
│     ├─ index.html
│     ├─ loan_business.php
│     ├─ loan_property.php
│     ├─ loan_register.php
│     ├─ loan_system.php
│     ├─ personal_loan.php
│     ├─ site.php
│     ├─ user
│     │  ├─ loan_register.php
│     │  └─ user.php
│     └─ welcome_message.php
```

Comment: please show your routes

Comment: @Vickel i have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following your directory tree:

you don't have a controller named `User.php` in your folder *controllers/user*. There is only one controller called `Auth.php`, therefore

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/user.php">
```

doesn't work, and returns a 404, file not found error

btw, the correct Codeigniter way to call that User.php controller would look like this:

```
<?php echo base_url('user/user');?>
```

either you add that controller, or you change the link to point to auth.php

read [Organizing Your Controllers into Sub-directories](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html?highlight=controller#organizing-your-controllers-into-sub-directories) 
and [URL Helper base_url()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=base_url#base_url)